# Permutations from columns of a data frame in R with specific conditions

Tags: r, random

This may be a rather complex question so if someone can at least point me in the right direction I can probably figure out the rest on my own.

Sample data:

```
dat <- data.frame(A = c(1, 4, 5, 3, NA, 5), B = c(6, 5, NA, 5, 3, 5), C = c(5, 3, 1, 5, 3, 7), D = c(5, NA, 3, 10, 4, 5))

   A  B C  D
1  1  6 5  5
2  4  5 3 NA
3  5 NA 1  3
4  3  5 5 10
5 NA  3 3  4
6  5  5 7  5
```

I would like to find all possible permutations of letter sequences of different lengths from the table shown above. For example, one valid letter sequence might be: `A C A D D B`. Another valid sequence could be `B C C`.

However, there are a few exceptions to this I'd like to follow:

#### 1. Must be able to specify the minimum length of the returned sequence.

Note that in my example above, the min sequence length was 3 and the max sequence length was equal to the number of rows. I would like to be able to specify the min value (the max value will always be equal to the number of rows, 6 in the case of the sample data).

Note that if the sequence length is shorter than 6, it cannot be generated from skipping rows. In other words, any short sequences must come from consecutive rows. **Clarification based on comments**: Short sequences do not have to start on row 1. A short sequence could start on row 3 and continue onward through consecutive rows to row 6.

#### 2. Letters with an NA value are not available for sampling.

Note that in row 2 there is an `NA` in the D column. This means that D would not be available for sampling in row 2. So `A B D` would be a valid combination but `A D D` would not be valid.

#### 3. The sequences must be ranked based on the values in each cell.

Notice how each cell has a specific value in it. Each sequence chosen can be ranked by summing up the value shown in the table for the chosen letter. Using the example from above `A C A D D B` would have a rank of `1+3+5+10+4+5`. So when generating all possible sequence they should be ordered from highest rank to lowest rank.

I would like to apply all three of these rules to the data table listed above to find all combinations of sequences possible of minimum length 3 and maximum length 6.

Please let me know if I need to clarify anything!

Comment: Are you trying to **sample** or to find all **permutations**? I think you want the latter (given a data frame structured as the one above, you get back all possible permutations that meet your structural requirements of length, ranked by score) but I wanted to confirm.

Comment: Also, you say that any short sequences must be done without skipping rows. Does this mean that you cannot skip *any rows at all* (i.e. that you must start each permutation with the first row)?

Comment: @TARehman You are correct, I am trying to find all **permutations**. The reason I had used the word sample was because you can get different sequences of the same length depending on which letter you chose (sampled from) the column. But I see now that permutations would cover all of those different possibilities.

Comment: @TARehman No, you can skip rows before the sequence starts (i.e. you can have a sequence starting on row 3). But then, following that the rest of the sequence cannot skip anything (so it would includes rows 3, 4, 5, and 6). I am going to edit my post for clarification, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, you want to do this using `expand.grid` I believe. Using your example data, I worked out the basics here:

```
dat <- data.frame(A = c(1, 4, 5, 3, NA, 5),
                  B = c(6, 5, NA, 5, 3, 5),
                  C = c(5, 3, 1, 5, 3, 7),
                  D = c(5, NA, 3, 10, 4, 5))

dat[,1][!is.na(dat[,1])] <- paste("A",na.omit(dat[,1]),sep="-")
dat[,2][!is.na(dat[,2])] <- paste("B",na.omit(dat[,2]),sep="-")
dat[,3][!is.na(dat[,3])] <- paste("C",na.omit(dat[,3]),sep="-")
dat[,4][!is.na(dat[,4])] <- paste("D",na.omit(dat[,4]),sep="-")

transp_data <- as.data.frame(t(dat))

data_list <- list(V1 = as.vector(na.omit(transp_data$V1)),
                  V2 = as.vector(na.omit(transp_data$V2)),
                  V3 = as.vector(na.omit(transp_data$V3)),
                  V4 = as.vector(na.omit(transp_data$V4)),
                  V5 = as.vector(na.omit(transp_data$V5)),
                  V6 = as.vector(na.omit(transp_data$V6)))
```

This code lets you essentially transform your data frame into a list of vectors of different lengths (one element for each variable in your original data, but omitting NAs and such). The reason you would want to do this is because it makes finding the acceptable combinations trivially easy by using the `expand.grid` function.

To solve for the six, you would simply use:

```
grid_6 <- do.call(what = expand.grid,
                  args = data_list)
```

This would give you a list of all possible permutations that met your criteria for the six (i.e. there were no NA elements). You can extract the numeric data back using some regular expressions (not a very vectorized way of doing it, but this is a complex thing that I don't have time to fully put into a function).

```
grid_6_letters <- grid_6
for(x in 1:ncol(grid_6_letters)) {

    for(y in 1:nrow(grid_6_letters)) {

        grid_6_letters[y,x] <- gsub(pattern = "-[0-9]*",replacement = "",x = grid_6_letters[y,x])
    }
}

grid_6_numbers <- grid_6
for(x in 1:ncol(grid_6_numbers)) {

    for(y in 1:nrow(grid_6_numbers)) {

        grid_6_numbers[y,x] <- gsub(pattern = "^[ABCD]-",replacement = "",x = grid_6_numbers[y,x])
    }
    grid_6_numbers[[x]] <- as.numeric(grid_6_numbers[[x]])
}

grid_6_letters$Total <- rowSums(grid_6_numbers)
grid_6_letters <- grid_6_letters[order(grid_6_letters$Total,decreasing = TRUE),]
```

Anyway, if you wanted to get the various lower-level combinations, you could do it by simply using `expand.grid` on subsets of the list and combining them using `rbind` (with some judicious use of `setNames` as needed. Example:

```
grid_3 <- rbind(setNames(do.call(what = expand.grid,args = list(data_list[1:3],stringsAsFactors = FALSE)),nm = c("V1","V2","V3")),
                setNames(do.call(what = expand.grid,args = list(data_list[2:4],stringsAsFactors = FALSE)),nm = c("V1","V2","V3")),
                setNames(do.call(what = expand.grid,args = list(data_list[3:5],stringsAsFactors = FALSE)),nm = c("V1","V2","V3")),
                setNames(do.call(what = expand.grid,args = list(data_list[4:6],stringsAsFactors = FALSE)),nm = c("V1","V2","V3")))
```

Anyway, with some time and programming, you can likely wrap this into a function that is much better than my example, but hopefully it will get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I don't do any R anymore, so I'll try to help with a dirty code...

```
addPointsToSequence <- function(seq0, currRow){
    i<-0;
    for(i in 1:4){# 4 is the number of columns
       seq2 = seq0
       if (!is.na(dat[currRow,i])){
           # add the point at the end of seq2
           seq2 = cbind(seq2,dat[currRow,i])
           # here I add the value, but you may prefer 
           # adding the colnames(dat)[i] and using the value to estimate the value of this sequence, in another variable
            if(length(seq2) >= 3){
            # save seq2 as an existing sequence where you need to
                print (seq2)
            }
           if(currRow < 6){# 6 is the number of rows in dat (use nrow?)
                addPointsToSequence(seq2, currRow+1)
           }
       }
    }
}


dat <- data.frame(A = c(1, 4, 5, 3, NA, 5), B = c(6, 5, NA, 5, 3, 5), C = c(5, 3, 1, 5, 3, 7), D = c(5, NA, 3, 10, 4, 5))

for (startingRow in 1:4){
#4 is the last row you can start from to make a length3 sequence 
   emptySequence <- {};
   addPointsToSequence(emptySequence , i);
}
```